# Paint event doesn't invoked

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, events, model-view-controller

Trying to implement a random walk by moving the ball across the screen. Algorithm is looks like working but debug shows that the paint event doesn't invoked.

First of all, try to do this in pattern MVC. For clarity, I will give the code of these components.

*View*:

```
 public partial class ViewBallBounce : Form, Observer
        {
            private ModelRandomWalk modelRandomWalk;
            private ControllerRandomWalk controllerRandomWalk;
            static int i = 0;
    
            public ViewBallBounce(ModelRandomWalk _modelRandomWalk)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                this.modelRandomWalk = _modelRandomWalk;
                controllerRandomWalk = new ControllerRandomWalk(modelRandomWalk, this, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height);
                
                modelRandomWalk.Register(this); 
    
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
                this.UpdateStyles();
            }
    
            public void UpdateState()
            {
                this.Refresh();
            }
    
            private void ViewBallBounce_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                controllerRandomWalk.Bounce();
            }
    
            private void ViewBallBounce_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.Clear(BackColor);
                i++;
                g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, modelRandomWalk.X, modelRandomWalk.Y,
                modelRandomWalk.Width, modelRandomWalk.Height);
                g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, modelRandomWalk.X, modelRandomWalk.Y,
                modelRandomWalk.Width, modelRandomWalk.Height);
            }
        }
```

*Control*:

```
public class ControllerRandomWalk
        {
            private ModelRandomWalk modelRandomWalk;
            private ViewBallBounce viewBallBounce;
            public int clientH, clientW;
    
            public ControllerRandomWalk(ModelRandomWalk modelRandomWalk, ViewBallBounce viewBallBounce, int _width, int _height)
            {
                this.modelRandomWalk = modelRandomWalk;
                this.viewBallBounce = viewBallBounce;
                this.clientH = _height;
                this.clientW = _width;
            }
    
            public int Bounce()
            {
                return modelRandomWalk.bounce(100, clientH, clientW); 
            }
        }
```

*Model*:

```
public class ModelRandomWalk
    {
        private int x, y;
        private int velocityX, velocityY;
        private int width, height; 

        public int X { get { return x; } }
        public int Y { get { return y; } }
        public int VelocityX { get { return velocityX; } }
        public int VelocityY { get { return velocityY; } }
        public int Width { get { return width; } }
        public int Height { get { return height; } }
 
        public void updatePosition(int key)
        {
            if (key == 0) this.x += velocityX;
            else this.y += velocityY;
        }
        public void updateVelocity(int key)
        {
            if (key == 0) this.velocityX = -this.velocityX;
            else this.velocityY = -this.velocityY;
        }
 

        public ModelRandomWalk(int _x, int _y, int _width, int _height)
        {
            this.x = _x;
            this.y = _y;
            this.width = _width;
            this.height = _height;
        }
 
        public int bounce(int _steps, int _h, int _w)
        {
            int steps = _steps;
            int clientH = _h, clientW = _w;
            for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int v = rnd.Next(0, 4); // 0 = +v_x, 1 = +v_y, 2 = -v_x, 3 = -v_y
                switch (v)
                {
                    case 0:
                        velocityX++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        velocityY++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        velocityX--;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        velocityY--;
                        break;
                }

                updatePosition(0);
                if (X < 0)
                {
                    x = 6;
                    updateVelocity(0);
                }
                else if (X + Width > clientW)
                {
                    x = clientW - 6;
                    updateVelocity(0);
                }

                updatePosition(1);
                if (Y < 0)
                {
                    y = 6;
                    updateVelocity(1);
                }
                else if (Y + Height > clientH)
                {
                    y = clientH - 6;
                    updateVelocity(1);
                }

                UpdateObservers();
            }
            return 0;
        } 

        private ArrayList listeners = new ArrayList();  
 
        public void Register(Observer o)
        {
            listeners.Add(o); 
            o.UpdateState(); 
        }
        public void Deregister(Observer o)
        {
            listeners.Remove(0);  
        }
        public void UpdateObservers()
        {
            foreach (Observer el in listeners)
            {
                el.UpdateState(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry for long post. The main problem in these lines, when ViewBallBounce_Paint doesn't invoke.

```
public void UpdateState()
            {
                this.Refresh();
            }

            private void ViewBallBounce_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.Clear(BackColor);
            i++; //just checking has it invoked
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, modelRandomWalk.X, modelRandomWalk.Y,
            modelRandomWalk.Width, modelRandomWalk.Height);
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, modelRandomWalk.X, modelRandomWalk.Y,
            modelRandomWalk.Width, modelRandomWalk.Height);
        }
```

I have tried a lot of ways to set breakpoints and don't understand why after Refresh nothing happens. By the way, breakpoint in ViewBallBounce_Paint shows very strange modelRandomWalk.X or modelRandomWalk.Y as 224 or -78 and they don't change.

What's could be wrong?

UPD: New form is openned and the ball is drawen but it doesn't move. Changed steps in cycle to 10 and find out ball had moved only after ending the cycle in Model Component. Nevertheless, this.Refresh has worked but the paint event has invoked after 10 iterations. By the way, the movement occurred taking into account the changes in speeds and positions in the Model component. Wrote Thread.Sleep(1000) in ViewBallBounce_Paint but there were no changes.

Comment: Is your `Paint` event attached to the `ViewBallBounce_Paint` function?

Comment: @Gusman, Paint was attached via Solution Explorer. The problem has changed a bit. Paint event is invoked after end of cycle in Model component but this.Refresh() is run. I thought this command must redraw the form immediately but it doesn't happen.

Comment: WinForms works through a message pump that runs on the main thread, if the thread is busy doing anything else it will be unable to process the messages so events aren't consumed until a bit of free time is available. Using WinForms for games is always a very bad idea as the performance is awful and as you have found you have no control at all about how it is going to be rendered.

Comment: If you want to stick to winforms then use a secondary thread to process your game logic (and use invoke where needed) or process a game tick on the Paint and do a contonuous call to Refresh(). But, the best would be to use something suited for games, like OpenGL, you can use OpenTK as it makes creating games very easy.